# Javascript - set new property based on other properties within an array inside the object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, foreach

Here is a data structure I'm working with

```
masterObject: {
  Steps: [
    {
      step: {
        required: false,
      },
      step: {
        required: false,
      },
      step: {
        required: false,
      },
    },
  ]
}
```

I'd like to loop through Steps array and check if all each step object contains propery required that is equal to false.
If all required steps are false I'd like to attach a property to the masterObject object of

```
masterObject.isObjectWithNoRequiredSteps = true;
```

which would look like this after the code runs

```
masterObject: {
  Steps: [
    {
      step: {
        required: false,
      },
      step: {
        required: false,
      },
      step: {
        required: false,
      },
    },
  ]
  isObjectWithNoRequiredSteps: true
}
```

If theres an example where one of the step object required is true I'd like to set the new property to false

```
masterObject.isObjectWithNoRequiredSteps = false;

masterObject: {
  Steps: [
    {
      step: {
        required: true,
      },
      step: {
        required: false,
      },
      step: {
        required: false,
      },
    },
  ]
  isObjectWithNoRequiredSteps: false
}
```

What is the best approach to setting this property on the higher level object?

Comment: You can't have same key name multiple times in an object at same level, your element in steps array is same as `[{step: { required : false }}]`

Answer (score 0):

The object inside `Steps` array has multiple attributes/keys with the same name `step`. This is not allowed in JavaScript. Consider changing your data structure as follows

```
masterObject: {Steps: [{ 
    step1: { required: false, }, 
    step2: { required: false, }, 
    step3: { required: false, },
}, ] }
```

Now, to determine if each step inside `Steps` array is false, use following code

```
masterObject.isObjectWithNoRequiredSteps = Object.keys(masterObject.Steps[0]).reduce(function(result, nextStep){
const isRequired = masterObject.Steps[0][nextStep].required; 
return !isRequired && result; 
}, true);
```